# Sort shops in ActiveRecord based on number of multiple products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a model called `Shop` that has many `Products`.

I'm trying to sort and display 10 shops at a time based on the number of Apples, Oranges and Mangoes the shop has.

Each shop will have more apples than oranges and more oranges than mangoes. The shops will be sorted beginning with the shop with the most apples.

What is the most efficient way to write this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is lacking information, therefore I will assume the following tables :

```
-------------      -----------------------------------------------------------
| Shop      |      | Stock                                                   |
-------------      -----------------------------------------------------------
| id | name |      | id | shop_id | apple_count | orange_count | mango_count |
-------------      -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, what you are asking for is *the rails way* to do this :

```
    select shop.name
          ,apple_count
          ,orange_count
          ,mango_count
      from current_stock
inner join shop on current_stock.shop_id = shop.shop_id
  order by apple_count  desc
          ,orange_count desc
          ,mango_count  desc
     limit 10
```

You can achieve that by doing the following :

```
Shop.joins(:stocks).order("apple_count desc, orange_count desc, mango_count desc").limit(10)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dominic,

Thanks for the answer. Sorry I should add more information:
`Shop has_many :products, :through => :stock`
`Product has_many :shops, :through => :stock`

`Stock` model has the `shop_id product_id`. There could be more than just apple, orange and mango products so therefore I created another model in between shop and product.

Comment: Also each shop must have more apples than any other products they carry.